# How to set your own ssrs default parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using a SSRS Parameter for my reports.

The parameter is populated by a Dataset - sql query.

```
select ProductName from  Product
```

I set these values using the **'Available Values'** option

I want to set the **Default Values** as **"Select"**

When I select the **No Default Value** , the output message I see is  is *** select a value"**

But my requirement is to see only **"Select"**

I dont see any other properties that I can set .
is it possible to set your own default parameter ?

Comment: What value do you gain by going through the effort of changing the message for no default value?  Is there a bigger picture where this connects into something else or is this purely cosmetic?

Comment: It is purely cosmetic. The user using the report wants it to be "Select" and not "select a value". Its a requirement from the user using the reports.

Comment: What do you mean by OUTPUT message ??? are you referring to Parameter Prompt ???

Comment: You have three Options to set your default value, NO Value, Specify Values, Get Values from a query which you are already doing . you can Specify value If you want to add values that dont exists anywhere in your database by why would you do that this will end up returning No values at all.

Comment: By OUTPUT Message "I meant the default value that shows up in the dropdown. I tried using "Specify Values" for the Default Value and set it as "Select" . But it still shows "select a value" as part of the default value in the drop down list.

Comment: I think you are mixing up Parameter default value with the Parameter Prompt. Go to that parameter right click --> Parameter Properties , there in General Tab you will see the Parameter Name and 2nd down The "Prompt" check there what you have as you Parameter Prompt :)

Answer (score 1):

The Available values determine what will be in the drop-down list. If you want "Select" to be in the list you will have to union that with your product names in the dataset query. The Default Values determine what is selected before you touch it. So your settings should look like this:

[image]

[image]