# ssrs - unable to set a "default value" when "available value" is set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to do the following as listed in another answer,

[How to set your own ssrs default parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337650/how-to-set-your-own-ssrs-default-parameter)

It's not working. The default value is not showing up. 
Any idea how to make this work?

Btw, I'm using this on a cascading parameter.

Comment: As the mentioned answer says `If you want "Select" to be in the list you will have to union that with your product names in the dataset query.`, did you `UNION` it with your dataset? Can you share the code for your dataset?

Comment: must the value specified in the "default values", be inside the results query returned by "available values"? I believe so.

Comment: @NickyvV, just read your answer. I believe that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you wanna add as an answer so I can accept your answer. :)

Comment: You can accept my answer if it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always implemented this the following way:

```
SELECT -1 AS ValueField
    ,'Select' AS LabelField
  --,OtherColumns

UNION ALL

--This is the query of your dataset
SELECT Id
    ,Value
  --,OtherColumns
FROM YourTable
```

This way the `Select` value can be set by using the default value in SSRS as you mentioned in your question.